# Wordpress Publish Date Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, date, metadata, shortcode

This sounds like it should be something simple or there should be a simple shortcode plug in to achieve this but i  have searched and searched for almost and hour now and can't find the answer. All i am trying to do is display the post's published date in the body text. Example: [meta = "Date"].  Is there an easy light weight solution to achieve this. I simply need to publish the post date inside the content.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

There is a good article on how to do this with a custom plugin or snippet of code for your theme

https://krogsgard.com/2012/create-a-shortcode-to-show-when-a-post-was-last-updated/

You can create a shortcode easily within WordPress.  This is a sample of code that you can either place in a new plugin file.  For creating a plugin file, visit https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin , basically, you create a file, lets say `my_shortcodes.php` and place it in the `/wp-content/plugins/` folder.  In that file, you would have the following.

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: My Plugin Stuff
Plugin URI: http://domain.com/
Description: My Plugin Stuff
Version: 0.1.0
Author: Your Name
Author URI: http://your-website.com/
License: GPLv2 or later
*/

function shortcode_post_published_date(){
 return get_the_date();
}
add_shortcode( 'post_published', 'shortcode_post_published_date' );
```

Then you would use the shortcode in your post `[post_published]`

**Disclaimer:**

This is a sample of what it may look like.  You may have to make some modifications to it to make it work the way you want.  You may not be able to copy and paste this into your code and it work right away.

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked like a charm. Had to make one change... Had to place the file into a folder before uploading into /plugins.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Great.  Glad it worked.  Please don't forget to mark correct answers and up vote to help others out know this answer helped